# meaning of "how could"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Because if that were true, that there’s a plan, it would mean there’s
>   a reason I live in Cincinnati, Ohio and my son robs banks. I would
>   have to believe that the only logical way for my life to go after the
>   riots in 2001 was to dream-up a non-profit called InkTank, to
>   encourage anybody who ever wanted to set things on fire to write down
>   the deepest, most hidden part of their hearts. How **could** something
>   so little and nothing (1), the act of getting people to pick up a pen
>   and listen to each other, to start to notice things, how **could**
>   that matter (2)? ([Kathy Holwadel](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/15305/))

It seems that **could**s mean ‘#7.used to emphasize how strongly you want to express your feelings ([OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/could))’ or ‘#5.used in statements that express a strong emotional reaction ([Merriam-Webster’s](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/could))’. Or the second might mean #4 on OALD or #2 on Merriam-Webster’s. Would you tell me which one do I have to pick up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's consistent with the first definition in either of those dictionaries.

> [modal verb] 1 — used as the past tense of can ▪ *How could something like this happen?*

But yes, you're correct that it fits #4 in the OALD and #2 in M-W. It's all about possibility.

In your quotation, it's restated for emphasis, but the question is, basically:

> How **was it possible that** something so little... matter[ed]?

The implicit statement here is that it's *impossible* (in the sense of *difficult to believe*) that a seemingly small alteration to someone's behavior could have any far-reaching, lasting effects.

“How could he?” Is a more common statement of a similar brand of disbelief.